# Problems using tkinter dropdown menu after using simpledialog

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, spyder

So, this is the code with the functions I am trying to run:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

workclass = ['Private', 'State gov', 'Never worked']


def create_root():
    global root 
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")

    global selected 
    selected = StringVar()


def change_dropdown(*args):
    global dropdown
    dropdown = str(selected.get())

def drop_workclass():
    create_root()
    # Create Label
    label = Label(root, text = "Workclass\n")
    label.pack()

    # Initial menu text
    selected.set("Select an Option")
  
    # Create Dropdown menu
    drop = OptionMenu(root, selected, *workclass)
    drop.pack()


    button = Button(root, text = "OK", command = root.destroy).pack(pady=20)
  
    selected.trace('w', change_dropdown)
    # Execute tkinter
    root.mainloop()
    return dropdown

def get_age():
    root = tk.Tk()

    root.withdraw()

    age = simpledialog.askstring(title=" ", prompt=" Age")

    return int(age)

def drop_exit():
    create_root()
    label = Label(root, text = "Exit the program?\n")
    label.pack()

    selected.set("Select an Option")

    drop = OptionMenu(root, selected, "Yes", "No")
    drop.pack()

    button = Button(root, text = "OK", command = root.destroy).pack(pady=20)

    selected.trace('w', change_dropdown)

    root.mainloop()
    return dropdown
```

The code runs well if I call the functions in this order, putting the simpledialog box (`get_age()`) as the last one to be called:

```
workclass_op = drop_workclass()
exit_op = drop_exit()
age = get_age()
```

But if I change the order and put `get_age()` at first or second, the dropdown boxes from the other functions don't work. First, the functions show a blank selection box but it's possible to select an option after clicking in the box, after selecting an option, the selected value is not saved and the program does not end the execution. The code below is the one I have problems with:

```
workclass_op = drop_workclass()
age = get_age() # Here the simpledialog function as the second one
exit_op = drop_exit()
```

In the code above, I can get the value from `drop_workclass()`, but not from `drop_exit()` because it is after `get_age()`, which is the one using the simpledialog tool.

The code doesn't run well even after interrupting the kernel and running it again. When I run it the second time I need to restart the kernel, otherwise, even the functions before `get_age()` don't run properly and I get the same issue as I explained before with all functions, not only the ones after `get_age()`.

Of course, the problem is inside the functions, but I don't know why, either where I am getting this error. I tried doing `root.destroy` in order to reboot the roots but it didn't work. I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: Multiple calls to `Tk()` result in multiple, entirely independent instances of the Tcl/Tk environment, that cannot interact at all - for example, a StringVar created in one instance cannot be updated by a widget created in a different instance.

Comment: There are several issues in your code: 1) create more than one instance of `Tk()`; 2) calling `mainloop()` more than once; 3) using same tkinter `StringVar` `selected` for both `OptionMenu` widgets.

Comment: Adding `root.destroy()` just before `return int(age)` in your `get_age` function, should work. Also when you create your `StringVar`, I would recommend you pass in `master=root`